# upload text file each line into mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

I have email.txt stored in my server the path of email.txt is

```
/home/xxxx/public_htnl/email.txt
```

email.txt consists of several thousand emails of subscriber which gets updated daily.
I want to import these emails to other database daily using cron.

I have tried this but its giving error

Could not load. `Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I think I don't have permission to run `LOAD DATA INFILE`

My code is:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test')
or die('Failed to connect');
mysql_select_db('test', $db);


$string = file_get_contents("http://www.xyz.com/email.txt", "r");
$myFile = "/home/xxx/public_html/email.txt";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("Could not open: " . mysql_error());
fwrite($fh, $string);
fclose($fh);


$result = mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '$myFile'" .
                  " INTO TABLE email");
if (!$result) {
die("Could not load. " . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Any other good method can be accepted.please don't advice that store data directly in other database while storing emails etc..

Comment: And you're sure that the password is correct?

Comment: @Palladium 100% sure and i have tried directly in phpmyadmin there also i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the root MySQL user, try running the query:

```
GRANT FILE on *.* to 'test'@'localhost';
```

If you still get the error, make sure your username and password for the test user are correct and that the host you are accessing MySQL from matches the host for the test user and password.

EDIT:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test') or die(mysql_error());

if (!mysql_select_db('test', $db)) die(mysql_error());

$emails = file("http://www.xyz.com/email.txt");

foreach($emails as $email) {
    $email = trim($email);
    if ($email == '' || strpos($email, '@') === false) continue;
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `email` VALUES('$email')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        echo "Failed to insert $email.  " . mysql_error() . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

If there are many, many emails, you can build an array of email addresses and do an extended insert every so often.

```
INSERT INTO emails VALUES('email1'), ('email2'), ('email3'), ('email4')
```

Comment: i dont have root access can you please give any other php code which will work

Comment: If you want to `LOAD DATA` then your account needs the `FILE` privilege.  Without that, you'll just have to read the file in a loop and issue INSERT statements as you read the file.

Comment: @user1515503 If you post what a few lines of the file look like I can make example PHP code if needed.

Comment: @deww010 every email in new line data is there in server with name email.txt pastorktang@cbcsd.com
jmartin@moneyconcepts.com
winter15heart@yahoo.com
lsanford10@athensacademy.org
td1545@att.com
welwel132@yahoo.com
bigdaddy692001me@yahoo.com
ksexton19@hotmail.com
daddysangle_p@yahoo.com

Comment: You mean the file is just one email address per line and nothing else?